# PHP remove unwanted input information & concatenate text fields

Tags: php, paypal, string-concatenation

I'm trying to create a deposit readonly reference field for my website and pass it to paypal as the invoice no. for identification. The reference no. is populated by the function date in the format of DD/MM/YY, firstname & the first character of the surname. (E.g. 05/07/13scottp)

I'd like required field validation on all editable fields and for the deposit reference to be populated after the user inputs the function date....

I'm a novice in PHP and am unsure where to start or the best practice of implementing my desired outcome.

I'm using a HTML form with the following code:

```
<form id="depositForm" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <div id="deposit-form" >
    <h1>Paying your deposit is Simple.....</h1>
    <p>Simply input all the details below, select your advised deposit option and click "Buy Now". It's that easy......</p>
    <p>Note: All fields marked <h7>*</h7> are required. Any Errors will be highlighted <h7>Red</h7>.

    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <label for="depositFirstname">*Firstname:</label>
    <label for="depositSurname">*Surname:</label>
    <label for="depositFunctiondate">*Function Date:</label>
    <label for="depositOp">*Select deposit option:</label>
    <label for="depositRef">Booking Reference:</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXXXXX">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
    <input type="hidden" name="country" value="United Kingdom" />
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Glimmer Nights Function Deposit">

    <input type="text" name="first_name" id="depositFirstname" />
    <input type="text" name="last_name" id="depositSurname" />
    <input type="text" name="depositFunctiondate" id="depositFunctiondate" />        
    <select size="1" name="amount" id="depositOp" class="input" />
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option name="amount" value="30.00">Option 1</option>
        <option name="amount" value="50.00">Option 2</option>
    <input type="text" name="invoice" id="depositRef" readonly="depositRef()" value="" />
    </td>
    </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Should you have any questions, please do not hesitate to contact us........</p>
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif"  name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Not a full answer, but either you will need to write javascript to set up the data for submission to paypal on the client side, or you will need to have the form action point back to your server to do validation and data packaging there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. Keep in mind that your form is going to POST its data to whatever address is listed in the `action` attribute of the `<form>` tag. In this case, you are sending all the form data directly to PayPal. You don't have an opportunity to run any PHP code before the data gets sent. Two choices:

1) change the `action` attribute on your form and POST the data to a PHP file on your own server. That file would do the processing and then send a new request on to PayPal.

2) This is probably easier. Use javascript to formulate the invoice number after the user clicks Submit but before the data gets sent. You can do this by adding an `onsubmit` attribute to the form. It'll look something like this:

```
<form id="depositForm" name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" onsubmit="generateInvoiceNo();" method="post">
```

Then create a javascript function by inserting a `<script>` block into the `<head>` region of your page:

```
<script>
    function generateInvoiceNo(){
        //get the date, user's first name and last initial
        var d = new Date();
        var curr_date = d.getDate();
        var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; 
        var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
        var datestr = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year.substr(2)
        var firstname = document.getElementById('depositFirstname').value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById('depositLastname').value; 
        //generate invoice number
        var invoicenum = datestr + firstname + lastname.substr(0,1);
        //put the invoice number into a hidden field on the form
        document.getElementById('depositRef').value = invoicenum;
    }
</script>
```

WARNING: I haven't tested the above code, but it should get you started.